# Detecting available API iOS vs. watchOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, watchos, watchos-2

`#available` does not seem to work when differentiating between watchOS and iOS.

Here is an example of code shared between iOS & watchOS:

```
lazy var session: WCSession = {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    return session
}()
```

...

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    guard session.paired else { throw WatchBridgeError.NotPaired } // paired is not available
    guard session.watchAppInstalled else { throw WatchBridgeError.NoWatchApp } // watchAppInstalled is not available
}

guard session.reachable else { throw WatchBridgeError.NoConnection }
```

Seems that it just defaults to WatchOS and the `#available` is not considered by the compiler.

Am I misusing this API or is there any other way to differentiate in code between iOS and WatchOS?

*Update: Seems like I was misusing the API as mentioned by BPCorp*

Using Tali's solution for above code works:

```
    #if os(iOS)
        guard session.paired else { throw WatchBridgeError.NotPaired }
        guard session.watchAppInstalled else { throw WatchBridgeError.NoWatchApp }
    #endif

    guard session.reachable else { throw WatchBridgeError.NoConnection }
```

Unfortunately there is no `#if os(watchOS)` .. as of Xcode 7 GM

**Edit: Not sure when it was added but you can now do `#if os(watchOS)` on Xcode 7.2**

Comment: if it is bug you can wait for `stable xcode 7`, anyways you will not be able to upload app to App Store from beta xcode.

Comment: @Aks, I was misusing the Api it's not a bug. Looks at BPCorp's answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to execute that code only on iOS, then use `#if os(iOS)` instead of the `if #available(iOS ...)`.

This way, you are not using a dynamic check for the version of your operating system, but are compiling a different code for one OS or the other.

Answer (score 7):

In the [Apple dev guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523), it is said that the star, `*` (which is required) means that it will execute the `if` body for OSes not specified but listed in the minimum deployment target specified by your target.

So, if your target specifies iOS **and** watchOS, your statement `if #available(iOS 9.0, *)` means that the `if`body is available for iOS 9 and later **and** any watchOS version.

Also, be careful if you want to use what's described in the chapter "Build Configurations" in this [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31). It is used to conditionally compile your code based on the operating system. This is not dynamic at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

With the GM version of Xcode7 I think they fixed that issue. For me :

```
if #available(watchOS 2,*) {
    // Only if using WatchOS 2 or higher
}
```

is working fine in GM version.

Comment: Doesn't work for cross compiled code for me. Instead #if os(iOS) works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, and `#if os(watchOS)` works.

Answer (score 1):

Time have passed since the question. If somebody still looking for the answer, need to say that
`#if os(watchOS)`
is now **available** in Xcode 13 and later.